# How to select multiple child node within a xml

Tags: xml, xpath, xquery

I got a xml look like this one

```
<Details>
  <UserResource>
    <ResourceGroup>AJD-IPSP1</ResourceGroup>
    <ResourceType>master</ResourceType>
    <Access>r</Access>
    <UseSOAPFault>soap </UseSOAPFault>
  </UserResource>
  <UserResource>
    <ResourceGroup>AJD-VME1</ResourceGroup>
    <ResourceType>trx</ResourceType>
    <Access>r</Access>
    <UseSOAPFault>soap </UseSOAPFault>
  </UserResource>
  <UserResource>
    <ResourceGroup>AJD-VME10</ResourceGroup>
    <ResourceType>trx</ResourceType>
    <Access>r</Access>
    <UseSOAPFault>soap </UseSOAPFault>
  </UserResource>
  <UserResource>
    <ResourceGroup>AJD-VME11</ResourceGroup>
    <ResourceType>trx</ResourceType>
    <Access>r</Access>
    <UseSOAPFault>soap </UseSOAPFault>
  </UserResource>
</Details>
```

what I am trying to achieve is:

```
/Details/UserResource[ResourceGroup="AJD-VME10" or ResourceGroup="AJD-VME1"]
```

The result is supposed to be

```
  <UserResource>
    <ResourceGroup>AJD-VME1</ResourceGroup>
    <ResourceType>trx</ResourceType>
    <Access>r</Access>
    <UseSOAPFault>soap </UseSOAPFault>
  </UserResource>
  <UserResource>
    <ResourceGroup>AJD-VME10</ResourceGroup>
    <ResourceType>trx</ResourceType>
    <Access>r</Access>
    <UseSOAPFault>soap </UseSOAPFault>
  </UserResource>
```

how can i do this xpath?

I want to do this one just using one xpath.

Comment: What is the problem? Doesn't the XPath expression in the question work?

Comment: You xPath expression seems to be working... Doesn't it? what's the output you get ?

Comment: I'm writing a db2 query.. SELECT SECTIONTITLE, VMETE.COALESCE_XML(XMLQUERY('$c/Details/UserResource[ResourceGroup="AJD-VME10" or ResourceGroup="AJD-VME1"]' passing i.SECTIONCONTENT as "c" ), i.SECTIONCONTENT) as SECTIONCONTENT FROM IPSP_CONFIGURATION i WHERE IPSPID='AJD-IPSP1' AND EFFECTIVETO='9999-12-31-23.59.59' doesn't work. but if I change the [ResourceGroup="AJD-VME10" or ResourceGroup = "AJD-VME1"] to [ResourceGroup="AJD-VME10"] it works. I think it might be a xpath problem.

Comment: Try [(ResourceGroup="AJD-VME10") OR (ResourceGroup = "AJD-VME1")], Also try replacing OR with |.

Comment: might be interesting for you - all db2 xml possibilities http://amolnpujari.wordpress.com/2008/04/12/db2-native-xml/

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple way to do it.  If you are comfortable with for loops, you could loop through each one of the UserResources and check if ResourceGroup/text() is equal to the term.

```
    let $x :=
<Details>
  <UserResource>
    <ResourceGroup>AJD-IPSP1</ResourceGroup>
    <ResourceType>master</ResourceType>
    <Access>r</Access>
    <UseSOAPFault>soap </UseSOAPFault>
  </UserResource>
  <UserResource>
    <ResourceGroup>AJD-VME1</ResourceGroup>
    <ResourceType>trx</ResourceType>
    <Access>r</Access>
    <UseSOAPFault>soap </UseSOAPFault>
  </UserResource>
  <UserResource>
    <ResourceGroup>AJD-VME10</ResourceGroup>
    <ResourceType>trx</ResourceType>
    <Access>r</Access>
    <UseSOAPFault>soap </UseSOAPFault>
  </UserResource>
  <UserResource>
    <ResourceGroup>AJD-VME11</ResourceGroup>
    <ResourceType>trx</ResourceType>
    <Access>r</Access>
    <UseSOAPFault>soap </UseSOAPFault>
  </UserResource>
</Details>


return $x/UserResource[ResourceGroup="AJD-VME10" or ResourceGroup="AJD-VME1"]
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an xsl solution:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:template match="Details">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="UserResource" />
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="UserResource">
    <xsl:if test="ResourceGroup='AJD-VME10' or ResourceGroup='AJD-VME1'">
        <xsl:element name="{name()}">
            <xsl:copy-of select="*" />
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:if>

</xsl:template>
```

Answer (score 0):

You say your DB2 query is

```
SELECT SECTIONTITLE, VMETE.COALESCE_XML( 
       XMLQUERY(
         '$c/Details/UserResource
          [ResourceGroup="AJD-VME10" 
          or ResourceGroup="AJD-VME1"]' 
          passing i.SECTIONCONTENT as "c" ), 
       i.SECTIONCONTENT) 
       as SECTIONCONTENT 
  FROM IPSP_CONFIGURATION i 
 WHERE IPSPID='AJD-IPSP1' 
   AND EFFECTIVETO='9999-12-31-23.59.59'
```

As others have already observed, the XPath here is syntactically and semantically correct; I would be inclined to suspect a possible hitch at the SQL/XQuery interface:  in the XQuery evaluation environment, is `$c` going to be bound to an element node for the `Details` element or to a document node with that element as its child?  That sort of thing is easy to get wrong, but simple to fix.

But then you say that that form *"doesn't work. but if I change the [ResourceGroup="AJD-VME10" or ResourceGroup = "AJD-VME1"] to [ResourceGroup="AJD-VME10"] it works.*

That's just weird.  If @Natkeeran's suggestion of parenthesizing the two disjuncts works, then the system you are using has a bug in its parser (which seems unlikely for DB2).  Are you absolutely sure that the only difference between a query that works as expected and one that returns nothing is the deletion of `or ResourceGroup="AJD-VME1"` from the predicate?